# What is the F# interactive window good for?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Am I able to script macros here? Maybe process some text? I may be interest in learning F# if this window provided the ability to process the current document, etc.

I have googled and found tutorials on learning F#, writing programs in F#, but nothing on what the F# interactive window is good for in VS.

EDIT:
Sounds like a rant yes. Is it? No. I love scripting. I just wrote a ruby script to implement an interface on a bunch of existing POCO's, that I couldn't easily figure out how to do with with ReSharper. I was thinking that if there was an interactive ruby console that could work with the current document(s) it would have made that task much easier. Then I got thinking that maybe that the F# console was what I was looking for, and it would be learning F# for.

Comment: IIRC, you can highlight a section of code and execute it. It is mostly for interactive testing.

Comment: sounds like a rant. Don't you have a real question?

Comment: So like the 'Immediate Window' on steriods I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

F# Interactive is a [Read-Eval-Print-Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (REPL), which is an ad-hoc environment that enables you to experiment with F# code. Many Functional programming languages come with a REPL.

You can highlight a piece of F# code in the normal editor and send it to F# Interactive with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can also write code directly in the F# Interactive. In order to focus in the window, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

F# Interactive is also available as the [command-line program fsi.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx), independent of Visual Studio. This makes F# accessible to people without access to Visual Studio.

There are various other ways to experiment with code and APIs. My personal preference is to use Test-Driven Development (TDD), which is one alternative to using a REPL. With TDD, I leave behind a suite of tests, which can often be beneficial. However, unit testing is a somewhat 'heavier' process, because I have to pull in a unit testing framework, and write assertions. Sometimes, I just need to experiment with various syntax alternatives or ways to model a concept, and the REPL provides more lightweight alternative to that. However, when I use F# Interactive, no test artefacts are left behind.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the main purpose of the F# Interactive windows is as a REPL for F# development. I find it useful for other tasks though too - you can use it as a sophisticated calculator, you can open files and process text and do many of the kinds of things you might use a bash window for on unix.

I have experimented a bit with accessing the Visual Studio Automation APIs from F# Interactive as described in [this blog post](http://fortysix-and-two.blogspot.ca/2010/05/accessing-visual-studios-automation-api.html). This is clearly not what FSI was originally intended for but it does make some of the things you seem to be interested in possible. I think it would be useful if this was directly supported in FSI but as it is I've found it a bit clunky to be really useful so far.